# Is there a way to include hyperlinks in nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, nodes, bloom

I am working on creating nodes and relationships. For a particular type of node, there is a hyperlink that I would like attach to it(perhaps as a property) so that users would be able to click and see more details on that node.

Does anyone know if that is possible? Happy to provide more details if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard string property would work just fine. It works as a regular hyperlink in the Neo4j browser.

```
CREATE (n:Sample {link: "https://google.com"}) RETURN n;
```

Comment: Thanks Aldrin. This worked.                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                           
 And for the rest of the folks who might end up here. Just FYI - Neo4j Browser, Bloom, Graph X(Kineviz) support hyperlinks and redirect you to the corresponding website when you click on the url/hyperlink. I am not sure about other tools since I haven't tested it out in those.